# Can AS3 recognize the CORS permissions from the header?

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, express, cors

I'm trying to go from Domain 1 using AS3 to hit Domain 2 running node.js/express

When I do

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
```

It tries to hit `[url]/crossdomain.xml` and gets a 404.

On the node.js server, running express, it returns the CORS stuff in the header, not as a stand-alone file on a specific route, like so:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
});
```

Is there anything I can do, besides putting the CORS file at `/crossdomain.xml`, that will enable AS3 to recognize the permissions being returned in the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way. You need crossdomain.xml at the root of your domain.

Answer (score -2):

> Can AS3 recognize the CORS permissions from the header?

Yes.